# Remove objects from default error list Spring boot validations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I am developing a Spring Boot Project and its a RestController and in webservice

`@ResponseBody CustomResponse method(final @PathVariable("tag") String tag, @Valid @RequestBody Payload payload, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) { }`

I get below response if signatureHeight is Null and in Payload class signatureHeight is annotated by `@NotNull`

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-08-01T13:30:41.859+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "Positive.Payload.signatureHeight",
        "Positive.signatureHeight",
        "Positive.int",
        "Positive"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "Payload.signatureHeight",
            "signatureHeight"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "signatureHeight",
          "code": "signatureHeight"
        }
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "must be greater than 0",
      "objectName": "Payload",
      "field": "signatureHeight",
      "rejectedValue": 0,
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "Positive"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='Payload'. Error count: 10",
  "path": "/e-sign/sign-pdf/XML"
}
```

I want to remove the `errors.codes` and `errors.arguments` from each object which will be present in the errors JsonArray.

Is this can be done easily without implementing own custom Error Object.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can.
But you need to implement [exception handling.](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

In your situation, the most common solution will be - to declare next code inside the controller:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ConstraintViolationException.class, MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
@ResponseBody
public ReturnType handleValidationException() {
    return ReturnType.somePreparedMessage();
}
```

Comment: How would I find which fields are having errors as there is no argument in the method.?

Comment: Sure you can't) But if you add the Cause, you can handle the response=) Hope it helps you

Comment: I just want to remove errors.codes from the default response handled by spring javax.validation.constraints not to implement my own custom

Comment: Can I temper the final response using Interceptor or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GlobalExceptionalHandler`. Here you handle all type of exception and return response && http status code as per your requirement.
Here is an example of method argument not valid exception handle. you can add more function for different type of exception with `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public void handleJsonException(HttpServletResponse response, Exception ex) {
    prepareErrorResponse(response,UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,"");
}


private void prepareErrorResponse(HttpServletResponse response, HttpStatus status, String apiError) {
    response.setStatus(status.value());
    try(PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter()) {
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(writer, apiError);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Error writing string to response body", ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I just want to remove errors.codes from the default response handled by spring javax.validation.constraints not to implement my own custom

Comment: If you want to customize response then you need to handle it

Comment: Can I temper the final response using Interceptor or something like that ?

Comment: you can use `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and override postHandle method

Comment: could you please edit that in your answer please.
I am trying to do the same but no success

Comment: because post  Handle is a void method

Comment: better to handle error response. it's not easy way to retrieve response body from httpservletresponse. look on it:  https://www.java-forums.org/java-servlet/20631-how-get-content-httpservletresponse.html